# PircBotX Private Message

Tags: java, message, private, bots, irc

when a user executes a command, I would like to send the output back to only that user, not the channel.

I'm using the PircBotX framework.

My Code:

```
public void onMessage(MessageEvent<PircBotX> event) {
    if (event.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("!test")){
        event.respond("Test Successful.");

    }else if (event.getMessage().split(" ")[1].equalsIgnoreCase("!test2")){
        event.getChannel().send().message("this response works");
        event.respond("This response works");
        event.getUser().send().message("but this does not work");
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://thelq.github.io/pircbotx/latest/apidocs/org/pircbotx/output/OutputUser.html#message(java.lang.String)), `event.getUser().send().message("XYZ");` should be a private message.

The [documentation](http://thelq.github.io/pircbotx/latest/apidocs/org/pircbotx/output/OutputUser.html#message(java.lang.String)) also states `bot.sendMessage` should be a private message, but that this doesn't work either.

For both of these, the console output looks completely normal.

One thought I have as to the origin of the issue: I'm building this as a Twitch.tv chat bot. It is possible (although [their API page](https://github.com/justintv/twitch-api) does not mention this) that private messages are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to send a whisper ?? if so take a look at this https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/sending-whispers-with-my-irc-bot/4346/6 you need to connect to an extra irc server to send whisper/private messages

Answer (score 0):

try `event.respondPrivateMessage("response");`

See [pirocbotx-docs](http://pircbotx.github.io/pircbotx/latest/apidocs/)->MessageEvent.respondPrivateMessage(String response)